# How many databases do I have on this MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I need to get a count of how many databases are living on my server. Should be a simple query, right?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually just want the count, and not a list you can also use a query like this.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

Comment: Thanks, y'all. For some reason google was not able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql:

```
  show schemas;
```

Quick & simple.